# Graphql multiple mutations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, mutation

I have 3 mutations in a query. 6 input parameters. If (profile_status === true), then send the mutation. And so for each mutation. How to do it?

```
mutation updateProfile(
   $input: UpdateProfileMutationInput!
   $input2: UpdateUserEmailMutationInput!
   $input3: UpdateUserPasswordMutationInput!

   $profile_status: Boolean!
   $email_status: Boolean!
   $password_status: Boolean!
) {
   @include(if: $profile_status) updateProfile(input: $input) {
     ...CoreUser
   }

   @include(if: $email_status) updateEmail(input: $input2) {
     ...CoreUpdateUserEmail
   }

   @include(if: $password_status) updatePassword(input: $input3) {
     ...CoreUpdateUserPassword
   }
}
```

I use **@apollo/client**.
Include only works for fields. Is there a similar one for mutation?

Answer (score 1):

From the [specification](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec--skip):

> The @skip directive may be provided for fields, fragment spreads, and inline fragments...

Implementation:

```
directive @skip(if: Boolean!) on FIELD | FRAGMENT_SPREAD | INLINE_FRAGMENT
```

As you can see, it doesn't have `MUTATION` location - it's not implemented for mutations. If you are the developer of the server, you can always create your own schema directive ([guide for Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/creating-directives/)).